# How to insert geo point into the Postgis database in Laravel 8?

Tags: geometry, laravel-8, postgis

I have Postgis database and table which contains column of type geography. Now I would like to make an Laravel insert but have no idea how to do it right. I have two values - latitude and longitude. Can somebody tell me please how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this

```
if ( isset($data['lat'], $data['long']) ) {
    $data['geo_point'] = "point({$data['lat']} {$data['long']})";
}

$audience = Audience::create($data);
```